# What is the definition of 'directory' in facebook platform policy?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook platform policy states: 'Don't put Facebook data in a search engine or directory, or include web search functionality on Facebook.'

What is the definition of 'directory'? I want to build an application that contains events for my city for today and tomorrow, events are retrieved from facebook graph api. Is it a 'directory'? It does not contain any search functionality (except looking city by name), just a page with events that are gonna happen today/tomorrow.
Is it a 'directory' or not? Is it legal to fetch this kind of information from facebook and store in my server?
This is just public events, no private data.